# Re-importing mlmodel in CreateML

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, coreml, createml

I'm testing the new awesome CreateML in an XCode playground.
I used the MLImageClassifierBuilder() with the live view feature to create my model, and saved it. 
Now I would like to re-import my .mlmodel file into my playground to run some more tests, but I didn't found a way to do it.

This seemed obvious to me to find this capability when I closed my playground.

Answer (score 1):

You can't continue training the same mlmodel. However, you can load the existing mlmodel and use it via the `MLModel` API, like so:

```
let compiledUrl = try MLModel.compileModel(at: modelUrl)
let model = try MLModel(contentsOf: compiledUrl)
model.prediction(....)
```

Never tried it myself, so I'm not 100% sure this works from a playground.